# Duplicate vs. replicate vs. reduplicate

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs, differences, synonyms

What is the difference in usage between these three apparently-synonymous words: *duplicate, replicate, and reduplicate*. (Definitions from ODO)

> *duplicate*: make or be an exact copy of
>   *replicate*: make an exact copy of; reproduce
>   *reduplicate*: repeat or copy so as to form another of the same kind

Why is it correct to say that the results of an experiment are replicated, but copies of a thesis are duplicated?

How should I discuss the following:

> Procedure X should work as though each node i in a graph were
>   replaced with v_i identical copies of it.

Have the nodes been replicated, duplicated, or reduplicated?  Should I reserve duplication for doubling in quantity?

Comment: Consult your local dictionary.

Comment: @Mahnax: I did, and I couldn't distinguish the definitions.

Comment: Edited to make less "general reference" (I hope)

Comment: I think, "duplicate" means more to make a copy (in case of the thesis e.g. to scan and print again) while "replicate" is more to do something again, that is, regarding the experiment, to repeat the test. For instance a replica can differ in result from the original (a replica of a artwork)

Comment: @AndrewLeach:  Thanks Andrew.  I've added the sentence I'm trying to write as well.  I didn't think it would be useful, but maybe it will improve the question.

Comment: @Neil G: it certainly _does_ improve the question (as did Andrew's edit). If a question looks like someone is merely using EL&U as a dictionary, then many will wonder why you didn't just use a dictionary. I listed a few other tips on writing good questions when I got on my soapbox [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/#2669), in case you're interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you replicate a finding, you may have come to the conclusion independently.

If you duplicate a finding, you have not come to the conclusion independently but have restated it.

Reduplication should be used only when something has been duplicated more than one time. If something has been duplicated exactly once, it is simply duplication.

Since your example sentence mentions "identical copies," duplication is more applicable than replication. Reduplication could be used if the procedure replaced the same nodes more than once but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Comment: The idea that "reduplicate" means *to duplicate again* makes total sense (I was led to this page by googling that very question), but it isn't compatible with the dictionary definition, quoted by NeilG above: *repeat or copy so as to form another of the same kind*.

Answer (score 3):

*Replicate* is used in the following sentences, where *duplicate* should not be used.

> It might be impractical to replicate eastern culture in the west.

> Interleukin-16 prevents the virus from replicating itself.

> These findings have been replicated by Atwood and Jackson.

When talking of genetic material, or a living organism, you don't say *duplicate* except in the case you mean *double* as in "the normal amount of DNA has been duplicated thousands of times."
When talking of scientific experiments, you could say "their experiment duplicated work already done," but in that case *duplicate* would mean "do something again unnecessarily."

In the example you make, I would say the nodes are duplicated. *Re-duplicated* would mean "duplicating something that duplicates something else": I duplicate node A to create node B, and I duplicate node B to make node C.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I look at it, but I could be wrong.

Duplicate: To make one exact copy of something.

Replicate: To make a general copy or copies of something, one or more times. ie: a printed copy of an original painting. (Make a replica)

Reduplicate: To make one or more exact copies of a duplicate.
To make more than one exact copy of something.

Comment: I don't see any restriction to a single duplicate (possible etymology aside). For example before photocopiers became widespread a less sophisticated process of producing multiple copies from an original was called duplicating using a machine called a duplicater.

Answer (score 1):

The linguistics meanings haven't been mooted yet. See [r/asklinguistics](https://redd.it/3n852c) -

> [reduplication (n.) 1580s, from French réduplication (16c.), from Late Latin reduplicationem (nominative reduplicatio), noun of action from past participle stem of reduplicare (see reduplicate).](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=reduplication&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> In other words, because it was borrowed into English in this form. I believe the synonym for "reduplicate" would be "to double", while the synonym for "duplicate" would be "to copy". Doubling let's say a key isn't the same as copying it.

Comment: I agree, it is often heard with reference to carrying on with, or extending, a pattern of some sort. As in reduplicating the fancy millwork of the old house in the new addition. It is also used technically in plant biology. Palm leaves consist of reduplicate leaf segments.

Answer (score -1):

"Duplicate" may also be employed per this discussion, tangentially, as an adjective or noun.

Adj. -- I will produce a duplicate blueprint.

Noun -- The second blueprint is a duplicate of the first.

Attempting to employ "Replicate" thus, sounds/read quite stilted to the native ear/eye.